# How to have continuous lines in tabulate in ConTeXt?

Tags: tables, context

When I create a tabulate in ConTeXt with vertical and horizontal lines, the vertical lines do not quite match up with the horizontal lines, leaving a space between them.

```
\starttext
    \starttabulate[l|l|l]
        \HL
        \VL a \VL b \VL c \VL\NR
        \HL
        \VL d \VL e \VL f \VL\NR
        \HL
        \VL g \VL h \VL i \VL\NR
        \HL
    \stoptabulate
\stoptext
```

How can I have continuous lines in a tabulate, so that the vertical and horizontal lines are connected?

Comment: Are you bound to tabulate or would xtables be an options for you?

Comment: No, but one requirement is that the tables be able to split in the middle of cells across pages. Tabulate does that fine. I don't know how to do that with any other kind of table in ConTeXt.

Comment: Oh, okay, with that requirement I would have to look it up myself. Probably a ConTeXt expert will have a solution with tabulate for you.

Comment: @Village Does my answer solve your problem?  If not, please explain where you find it to be lacking.  I have also browsed your profile and found that you have several questions with no accepted answer.  Please review them and accept answers or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `distance=medium`.  You have to set it to `distance=none`.  Either locally

```
\starttext
    \starttabulate[l|l|l][distance=none]
        \HL
        \VL a \VL b \VL c \VL\NR
        \HL
        \VL d \VL e \VL f \VL\NR
        \HL
        \VL g \VL h \VL i \VL\NR
        \HL
    \stoptabulate
\stoptext
```

or globally with `\setuptabulate[distance=none]`.

[image]